# Google Maps Polyline Colour Ignored in IE - UTF8 BOM prime suspect

Tags: google-maps, utf-8, notepad++, multilingual, byte-order-mark

I've recently been upgrading the pages for my website from the Google Maps API v2 to API v3 and I've noticed that the polyline colour property is ignored by IE but honoured by FireFox and Chrome. The polylines are shown in different colours in Chrome and FF but in IE they are just the default black. Example link:

http://www.bestbikingroads.com/motorcycle-roads/motorbike-rides-in-united-states-/Nevada_-3752.html

I'm using Notepad++ to code my site in PHP

I have a suspicion that this might be caused by an ongoing problem that I seem to have with the UTF BOM. The reason I suspect this because when I use Notepad++ and 'convert to UTF8 without BOM' the polyline colour problem then also happens in FF

Any ideas appreciated, I have previously tried to recode all the files to UT8 without BOM but this seems to introduce all kinds of problems with non-english chars being shown properly so up to now I have just put up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save without the BOM in any case.

The problem I see is that you have the Content-Type-`<META>` set to utf-8, but this will not have any effect, because the server sends a content-type-header:

```
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

...what will have precedence before the `<meta>`

You should setup the server to send the desired header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have now updated the server response to UTF8 and converted all the pages to UTF8 without BOM. Sadly however, this has not helped. Oh well!

Comment: strokeColor expects a css-color, you've obtained the required # in front of the hex-color-value here: `var strokeColor = "484848";`

Comment: Hi there, now that the whole of the DB has been converted to UTF8, the PHP pages converted to UTF8 without bom and the meta tag set to UTF8, the non-english characters are no longer displayed correctly. I'm looking for a solution but have had no luck so far, an example page is : http://www.bestbikingroads.com/motorcycle-roads/motorbike-rides-in-albania-/albania-__7102.html if you have any advice on how this might be resolved I'd be interested to hear. David

Comment: Anyway, I needed to change the server response back to 8859-1 for the time being to get the characters to display correctly, if you have a minute I have a UTF-8 version of the same page here: http://www.bestbikingroads.com/cr.php?code=7102 if you have any suggestions, I'd be interested to hear, David

Comment: When you say you converted the DB to UTF8, did you also set charset of the DB-connection to UTF8?

Comment: Aha! I must admit that I had not set the db connection charset to UTF8. That seems to have have been the missing piece of the puzzle! A big thanks to you for taking the the time to look into this with me. I owe you a virtual beer :)